# Selenium Webdriver POI multiple login from Excel sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I want to test login page with multiple credentials using Excel(.xls), already imported the POI jar files.
Simple code is preferred with not too many classes.

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.. i goth the solution

below code works fine

File file = new File("D:\Automation practice\ParamData\DataIngestParam.xls");

```
     try {
         iFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
         wb = new HSSFWorkbook(iFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }     

     HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1"); 
     int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
     System.out.println("the no of rows are : " + rowCount);

     for (int row=1; row<=rowCount; row++){

     Comment = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
     Input = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

     Output = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jps_main_panel']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/div")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jps_main_panel']/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(Comment);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jps_main_panel']/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input")).sendKeys(Input);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jps_main_panel']/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input")).sendKeys(Output);
```